# When I try to login with facebook I got permission error

Tags: facebook

I create a app and set up it here
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

I add a tester account there and use it to login from my app but I got the error message:

```
    This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.
```

Some answers about this question is to public my app but it's still on development process. Should I supposed to public the app? Or any other way to test it?

Comment: No, you do not need to make your app public to be able to test it with a user that has been assigned a role in the app, or a test user. // Please double-check that you used the right app id in your code (having that wrong is a common cause for this error appearing unexpectedly.)

Comment: @CBroe Thank for your help. I check the app id again and it's correct. I can login in with a developer account but the tester account not working.

Comment: Just to be clear, by adding a tester you mean you added a real existing user profile in the Roles section in the app dashboard? That user should then have gotten a request to become a tester for your app, which they need to confirm first.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your help. I received account from my coworker so I don't know if the tester get a request or not. But I just deleted the user and added it again. and It works now. When I added the tester I found out the user and developer are not friends in facebook. So I send a friends request to the user to make them friends. Does it matter?

Comment: Since it says directly in the dialog that comes up when you add a test user, “To add someone you aren't friends with on Facebook, enter their fbid or username”, I suppose it doesn’t ...